# $f$ has a bounded derivative, then $x+cf(x)$ is surjective

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to solve this question:

> Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be a derivable function with $|f'(x)|\leq k$, prove that
>   there is a constant $c\in \mathbb R$ such that the function $g:\mathbb
> R\to \mathbb R$ defined by $g(x)=x+cf(x)$ is a diffeomorphism.

I put $c=\frac {1}{k+1}$, then $g'(x)$ is always positive, then $g$ is injective (because it's strictly increasing).

The diffeomorphism part is easy, because $g$ is derivable and $g^{-1}$ is also derivable (because $g' \neq 0$)
However, I'm having trouble proving the surjectivity.

Comment: Continuous+positive derivative+limit at $\pm\infty$ is $\pm\infty$ (with sign changes, of course) all together imply that the function is surjective. You just have to show, then, the two limits at infinity.

Comment: @AsafKaragila yes, but how can I do that? It seems hard.

Comment: Well, take a real number $M$ and show that there are $x_1,x_2$ such that $g(x_1)<M<g(x_2)$.

Comment: @BenjaLim: No, $g^{-1}$ is defined if $g$ is injective. You know its domain is $\mathbb R$ only after you know the function is surjective.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I didn't understand why proving this, we prove the surjectivity. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Did you mean codomain?

Comment: @BenjaLim: No. I meant domain. Stop thinking like a category theorists; and think like a set theorist for a moment. Functions are sets of ordered pairs, not triplets of domain-codomain-map.

Comment: @user42912: If $h\colon\Bbb{R\to R}$ is continuous, injective, and $h(-\infty)=-\infty, h(\infty)=\infty$ then $h$ is surjective as well. This is essentially the intermediate value theorem for $[-\infty,+\infty]$.

Answer (score 6):

For any $c \in (0,\frac{1}{k})$ and any $x > 0$ and $y < 0$,

Apply MVT to g on $[0,x] \implies \exists \xi \in (0,x)$ such that:

$$\begin{align}
&g(x) - g(0) = g'(\xi) (x - 0) = (1 + c f'(\xi)) x \ge (1 - ck)x\\
\implies & g(x) \ge g(0) + (1 - ck) x
\end{align}$$

This means $g(x)$ is unbounded above as $x \to +\infty$.

Apply MVT to g on $[y,0] \implies \exists \zeta \in (y, 0)$ such that:

$$\begin{align}
         &g(0) - g(y) = g'(\zeta)(0 - y) = (1 + c f'(\zeta)) |y| \ge (1 - ck) |y|\\
\implies &g(y) \le g(0) - (1-ck) |y|
\end{align}$$

This means $g(y)$ is unbounded below as $y \to -\infty$.

For any number $d \in \mathbb{R}$, take a $x$ sufficiently positive such that $g(x) > d$ and a $y$ sufficiently negative such that $g(y) < d$, then by IVT, there is a $z \in (y,x)$ such that $g(z) = d$. i.e. $g$ is surjective.